# How can I set a floats width to the left over space?

Tags: html, css

I want to display 3 divs horizontally aligned to each other. So I create a main div (100%) and put the three divs inside that. In css I set those three childdivs to float:left.

Now what I want is to set the first two to a fixed width and set the third one to the width that is left over.

I know table-columns have a width:auto; that automaticaly fills the left over space, but I don't want to use tables. So how can I do this with floats?

Comment: have you tried using `display: table-cell` for `<div>` instead of `float: left`? that's pretty basic stuff

Comment: I don't think you can with floats; floated elements take their own natural width up to a maximum of the width of their layout container but I know of no way within the box model to ask a floated element to take "all the width left over" by other elements. You could javascript it (yuck!) or you could just use more appropriate styling than float - see good answers from others.

Comment: What if you don't float the third div? And perhaps add `overflow: hidden;` to it, to create a new block formatting context?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/freshbm/NPpAW/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `overflow:hidden` on the third column and it will automatically take up the remaining space. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/ApPeS/1/).

### Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.one, .two {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 400px;
}

.three {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note that the third column should not be floated.

Comment: First two divs should have **fixed** width.

Comment: That's fine. It still works. I updated [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/ApPeS/1/) and the code.

Comment: it's beautiful in all its simplicity! Thanks! This answers my question

Comment: And the best thing is that you don't even have to have `overflow: hidden;`!

Answer (score 0):

As Ejay suggested use the display: table for the outer div and display: table-cell for the inner divs.

Comment: Never used display:table before, but it's a nice trick to have. Thanks!